# C# Add a blank value in between string in of CSV file

Tags: c#, string, csv

I have this on a string that is generated from a list how can I add a blank value in between the string.

```
       using (var file = File.CreateText()
        {
            foreach (var permutation in result)
            {
                file.WriteLine(string.Join(",", permutation));
                //i++;

            }
        }
```

Here is the result:

string result = A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J

How can I add a blank value ", ," in the result at a specific index

Example: A,B,C,D,E,F, ,G,H,I,J

Note: result is a permutation and length is not consistent

Result is a IEnumerable can it be split?

Comment: use a loop `for` you will easly know your index.

Comment: [`string.Insert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Btw if the element was in the `permutation` collection then the result will be good and you would not have to modify it. What type is `var permutation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your string with the comma as the separator, go through your characters and add them to a list. Add an extra empty string at your desired index and join the data back together. This way you don't have to deal with deciding if you need to add a commar or not when concatenating the strings.

```
var index = 6;

var data = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J";
var chars = data.Split(new [] { ',' });

List<string> resultData = new List<string>();

var i = 0;
foreach (var c in chars) {                                              
    if (i == index) {
        resultData.Add(" ");
    }

    i++;

    resultData.Add(c);
}

var result = string.Join(",", resultData.ToArray();
```

Comment: forgot to add that result is a  IEnumerable<string> can it be split?

Comment: If your initial data is already an IEnumerable<string> then you can just leave the splitting part out and use that data in the foreach loop in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following basic algorithm to follow your questions code logic:

```
        using (var file = File.CreateText())
        {
            int i = -1;// Loop counter
            int termReplacementIndex = 3;// Input or constant to find letter to replace

            foreach (var permutation in result)
            {
                i++;

                if (i == ((termReplacementIndex * 2) - 2))// Only stops on letters not commas
                {
                    file.WriteLine(string.Join(",", " ,"));// Adding of blank " "
                }
                file.WriteLine(string.Join(",", permutation));// Adding of letter
            }
        }
```

Comment: Otherwise you could use an array to break apart the string into chars, splitting on commas

Answer (score 0):

If permutation is a list you can just insert a null value at the required index:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        list.Add("test 1");
        list.Add("test 2");
        list.Add("test 3");

        list.Insert(2, null);

        var str = string.Join(",", list);

        Console.WriteLine(str); // test 1,test 2,,test 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the Collection before joining it so you wont have to split it and iterate it again.
As the side of `permutation` vary you could be trying to insert at index X when X is larger greater `permutation.Count()` instead of an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` I decide to add the element at the end. But you will have to define that.

```
public string CsvProjection(List<string> inputs, int needleIndex, string needleValue)
{
    if (needleIndex < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("needleIndex must be positive.");
    }
    if (needleIndex > inputs.Count())
    {//Either throw an exception because out of bound or add to the end
        inputs.Add(needleValue);
    }
    inputs.Insert(needleIndex, needleValue);
    return string.Join(",", inputs);
}
```

Usage simply add the value and the index variable:

```
var needleIndex= 2; 
var needleValue = "My New Value";

using (var file = File.CreateText()
{
    foreach (var permutation in result)
    {
        file.WriteLine(CsvProjection(permutation, needleIndex, needleValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: the heck is a "neddle"?

Comment: @Nyerguds, fixed. it was a typo E and D are really close. Blame dislexia or friday post.   Searching for "C# Needle insert" and "C# needleIndex", gave a lot of close result. So I guess the word needle is not missused there. For inserting one element into an array, with this idea of pin pointing where.  But my English is bad, it could simply be the wrong term.